# javascript scope, why does $(this) equal [window]?

Tags: javascript, scope

I have an ajax function (not sure if relevant) that updates html and creates a few links:

```
<a href="#" class="clickme" onclick="column_click()" title="my title">click me</a>
```

I'm not sure why, but onclick, if I alert `$(this).attr('title')` it shows as `undefined`, and if I alert `$(this)` it shows `[window]`

```
     function column_click(){
            value = $(this);
            console.log(value);

            thetitle= $(this).attr('title');
            console.log(thetitle);
        }
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Show your click handler?

Comment: Are you sure that handler is attached to link, not window? What's your JS code?

Comment: So you're using jQuery? Why inline JavaScript? Where are your variables declared? `value = $(this)`???

Comment: Shouldn't that be `onclick="column_click()"` so you call the function? In the function, you can do `this.title` instead of the `$(...).attr(...)` stuff, it's very much more efficient.

Comment: You should read about [`this` in general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [`this` inside event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing the obtrusive and unobtrusive styles of JS/jQuery event handling. In the unobtrusive style, you set up click handlers in the JavaScript itself, rather than in an `onclick` attribute:

```
$('.clickme').on('click', column_click);
```

The above will automatically bind `this` to the clicked element while the event is being handled.

However, this is not standard JavaScript! It's a feature of jQuery. The `on` method is smart enough to bind the function to the HTML element when it handles the event. `onclick="column_click"` doesn't do this, because it isn't jQuery. It uses standard JS behavior, which is to bind `this` to the global object `window` by default.

By the way, the reason you see `[window]` is that `$(this)` has wrapped `window` in a jQuery object, so it looks like an array with the `window` object inside it.

There are three main ways to deal with your problem:

1. Use unobtrusive binding: `$('.clickme').on('click', column_click);` in a script at the end of the page, or somewhere in the `$(document).ready` handler
2. Bind `this` manually: `onclick="column_click.call(this)"`
3. Avoid using `this` at all:

   ```
   function column_click(e) {
       var value = $(e.target);
       //...
   ```

Of these, I'd strongly recommend either 1 or 3 for the sake of good coding.

Comment: +1, but clean up your first sentence. This isn't about *obtrusive* vs *unobtrusive* styles. You can write unobtrusive JS perfectly well without jQuery. `document.getElementsByClassName('clickme')[0].onclick = column_click;`

Comment: `onclick="column_click.call(this)"` should be `onclick= column_click;`. Also `e.target` will fail in browsers that don't support `event.target` (various versions of IE at least).

Comment: Saying `[setting the element to this] is not standard JavaScript` is incorrect. jQuery does it because that's how javascript has always done it.

Comment: @RobG - Doing it *automatically* is not standard JavaScript, however. Without jQuery to do it for you, you have to do it manually with `call`, `bind`, or `apply`. This is the source of the asker's problem.

Comment: In event handlers, no matter how they are bound (HTML attributes, DOM properties, DOM3 event handling), `this` always refers to the element the handler was bound to. The only exception is IE's `attachEvent` (unfortunately). Another confusion is that the content of the `onclick` attribute is the body of the event handler, not the function that is called from it, therefore `this` does not refer to the element inside the function but "inside the attribute value".

Comment: I'm unsure on the `onclick` version. It's not my usual style of event handling. However, it appears to behave as I predicted: http://jsfiddle.net/r7GDb/ vs. http://jsfiddle.net/r7GDb/1/ Actually, I'm at a loss to explain this, because as I look at it I feel like it really should be `onclick="column_click"`.

Comment: As I said, the value of the attribute is the *function body*. `onclick="column_click"` is the same as writing `element.onclick = function() { column_click; };`, i.e. no function is executed inside the body. And that `onclick="column_click.call(this)"` works is completely in line with what I said.

Comment: @Felix - That makes sense. I had it right the first time, but I was seeing it as a callback for a second there. Like I said, not my usual style of event handling.

Answer (score 3):

This should fix the issue.

```
onclick="column_click.call(this);"
```

The reason is that your "click handler" is really just a function. The default is to have `this` refer to the `window` object.

In my example above, we are saying "execute `column_click` and make sure `this` refers to the `a` element.

Answer (score 2):

### A Short Overview of `this`***

When you execute a function in JavaScript, the default `this` is `window`.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

foo(); // => window
```

The `this` value can be changed in a number of ways. One way is to call the function as a method of an object:

```
var x = {
    foo: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};
x.foo(); // => This time it's the x object.
```

Another way is to use `call` or `apply` to tell the function to execute in the context of a certain object.

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}
foo.call(x); // => x object again
foo.apply(x); // => x object as well
```

If you `call` or `apply` on `null` or `undefined`, the default behavior will occur again: the function will be executed in the context of `window`:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}
foo.call(null); // => window
foo.apply(undefined); // => window
```

However, note that in ECMAScript 5 **strict mode**, `this` does not default to window:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    function foo() {
        console.log(this);
    }

    foo(); // => undefined
    foo.call(null); // => null
    foo.apply(undefined); // => undefined

})();
```

You can also set the `this` by using `bind` to bind the function to an object before it is called:

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this);
}

var bar = {
    baz: 'some property'
};

var foobar = foo.bind(bar);

foobar(); // => calls foo with bar as this
```

### Conclusion

You're using this code:

```
<a href="#" class="clickme" onclick="column_click()" title="my title">click me</a>
```

Which means that when the link is clicked, it executes `column_click();`. That means the `column_click` function gets executed as a plain function, not a method, because (1) it's not called as a property of an object (`someobject.column_click();`), (2) it's not called with `call` or `apply`, and (3) it's not called with `bind`. Since it's not running in strict mode, the default `this` is `window`.

### How to Fix Your Problem

Therefore, to fix your problem, you can simply use `call` (or `apply`) to tell the function to execute in the context of the element. Within the small code inside the attribute value, `this` refers to the element. So we can use `column_click.call(this)`. It's that easy!

```
<a href="#" class="clickme" onclick="column_click.call(this);" title="my title">click me</a>
```

However, it would probably make more sense just to pass the element as an argument:

```
<a href="#" class="clickme" onclick="column_click(this);" title="my title">click me</a>
```

and change your function to accept the argument:

```
function column_click(el) {
    // Use el instead of this...
}
```

***  **Getting Technical**

`this` in JavaScript is **dynamically scoped**. This behavior differs from all other variables which are **lexically scoped**. Other variables don't have a different binding depending on *how* the function is called; their scope comes from *where* they appear in the script. `this` however behaves differently, and can have a different binding depending not on *where* it appears in the script but on *how* it's called. This can be a source of confusion for people learning the language, but mastering it is necessary in order to become a proficient JavaScript developer.

Comment: Good work, but I think totally lost on the OP. BTW, you don't "change" `this`, but set it by the call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the parameter in the function of `column_click`,

```
<a href="#" class="clickme" onclick="column_click(this)" title="my title">click me</a>



function column_click(obj){
        value = $(obj);
        console.log(value);
    }
```

Note: `this` refer `window` object. so won't work what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery right?  Why not:

```
$(".clickme").click(function() {
  value = $(this);
  console.log(value);

  thetitle= $(this).attr('title');
  console.log(thetitle);
});

// or

$(".clickme").click(column_click);
```