# Global Variable outside of function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I have tried a bunch of different ways to avoid getting undefined from a global variable but it messes up the rest of the code. I am able to call the variable this.userHunger in all functions but a few. I know i must have gone wrong somewhere:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function user() 
{
    this.userHunger = 100;
    this.userHealth = 100;
    this.userFoodNumber = 10;

    this.checkForHungerHealthData = function() 
    {
        document.getElementById('userHealthDisplay').innerHTML = "Your Health:" + this.userHealth;
        document.getElementById('HungerBarVisual').innerHTML = "Your Hunger" + this.userHunger;
        document.getElementById('amountOfFood').innerHTML = "Amount of food" + this.userFoodNumber;
    }

    this.signInButton = function()
    {
        document.getElementById('myButtonSignIn').style.visibility="hidden";
        this.checkForHungerHealthData(); // displays current hunger and health
    }

    this.eatFood = function() 
    {
        if(this.userFoodNumber  > 0) 
        {
            this.userHealth = this.userHealth + 10;
            this.userHunger = this.userHunger + 50;
            this.userFoodNumber--;
            document.getElementById('amountOfFood').innerHTML = "Amount of food:" + this.userFoodNumber;
            document.getElementById('userHealthDisplay').innerHTML = "Your Health:" + this.userHealth;
            document.getElementById('HungerBarVisual').innerHTML = "Your Hunger is currently " + this.userHunger + "%";
        }
    }

    this.start=function()
    {
        this.hungerClockStart();
    }

    this.hungerClockStart=function()
    {
        this.setUserHungerClock(setInterval(this.updateHungerScreen,1000));
    }

    this.updateHungerScreen=function()
    {
        alert(this.userHunger); //Returns undefined
        if(this.userHunger >= 0) 
        {
            var subtractAmount=1;
            document.getElementById('HungerBarVisual').innerHTML = "Hunger is Currently at: " + this.userHunger + "%";
            this.userHunger--;
        }
    }
}

var user1 = new user();

</script>
</head>
<h1 id = "userHealthDisplay">Your Health:<br></h1>
<h1 id = "HungerBarVisual">Your Hunger:<br></h1>

<input id="myButtonSignIn" style="visibility:visible" type="button" value="Sign in" onclick="user1.signInButton(); user1.hungerClockStart()">

<body>
<h1 id = 'Notifyer1'><br></h1>
<h1 id = 'Notifyer2'><br></h1>
<h1 id = 'amountOfFood'>Amount of Food:</h1>
<input id="eatFoodButton" style="visibility:visible" type="button" value="Eat some food!" onclick="user1.eatFood()">

</body>
</html>
```

I keep getting an error inside the this.hungerScreenUpdate and cannot understand why.

Comment: Why do you keep using `this`?

Comment: There is no `this.hungerScreenUpdate`

Comment: Sorry i  meant to say this.UpdateHungerScreen

Answer (score 2):

```
this.setUserHungerClock(setInterval(this.updateHungerScreen,1000));
```

needs to be

```
this.setUserHungerClock(setInterval(this.updateHungerScreen.bind(this),1000));
```

In JavaScript, `this` is dynamic, not lexical, so `this` can change depending on how it's called. When you do `setInterval(this.updateHungerScreen,1000)` it doesn't call `updateHungerScreen` with the correct `this` value. You can use `bind` to bind a function to a specific context.

---

As the commenters have suggested, if you need it to work on IE8 and below, you need to either shim in `bind` or use Phrogz's technique of storing `this` as a variable.

---

### Update

For an overview of how `this` works in JavaScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13373383/1662998

Personally, I recommend shimming in `bind` for IE8 and below. That way you get to go ahead and use new features while maintaining backwards compatibility with older browsers. Just add this in a script at the top of your page, and you'll be good to go:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind)
    Function.prototype.bind = function(context/*, ...preArgs */) {

        var f = this,
            preArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

        if (typeof f != 'function')
            throw new TypeError('Function expected.');

        if (context != null)
            context = Object(context);

        return function bound(/* ...args */) {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            return f.apply(context, preArgs.concat(args));
        };

    };
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that `Function.bind` is an ES5 feature and won't be available in versions of IE less than IE 9.

Comment: Basically, this is sometimes that, not this.

Comment: Alternatively, for compatibility with non-modern browsers: `var me=this; this.setUHC( setInterval(function(){ me.updateHungerScreen() },1000) );`

Comment: @Phrogz you beat me to it. Justin, look up javascript closures.

Comment: I suggest, Nathan, that you add a closure-based variant to your answer also. I do not mind if you take the contents of my comment wholesale; I will delete it if you add it to the answer.